# Does Using VBA in Microsoft Office Slow Down the Program Significantly?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, performance, vba, microsoft-office

I've never used VBA before.  Does having it "on" slow down the program for all files that don't use VBA within its document?  I was always scared that if I add a Macros/VBA in just one file, this will open up processes that will slow down my computer for documents that don't use VBA.

I can see Macros/VBA not making a difference to your computing session if you never open up a document that contains VBA but I can see the possibility that it does still make a difference.  Does it?

Now, if I use a document that has a VBA and then I close the document and open another, will Microsoft Office be a little bit slower with background processes unclosed?

Answer (score 1):

VBA code only uses computer resources when it is being executed, but not otherwise.

These resources are used by Word (or other Office products), so when Word is closed
no resources or processes are left over.

The only possibility that this would happen is if the VBA code got into a loop,
so Word cannot close properly.

Comment: Thanks.  That's very reassuring.  Would you happen to know if just the VBA console itself slow the program considerably?  I assume that if you have a complicated VBA script it would slow it down noticeably but if it's a simple script, is there any noticeable effect?

Comment: I never noticed a slow-down with my simple scripts.

Answer (score 1):

In general, after you close the VBA console, it does not leave a process in the background that affects your use.

If there is a while (1) loop in the program or a thread that has not yet exited, there will be a residual procedure in the background.

Comment: Your answer makes me doubly reassured!  A lot of people answer when they don't really know the answer but 2 out of 2 is good.  Thank you for your answer.  By the way, would you happen to know if just the VBA console itself slows the program considerably?  I assume that if you have a complicated VBA script it would slow the Office program down noticeably but if it's a simple script, is there any noticeable effect?